# Can I use the Android Bluetooth API on regular Linux distros?

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Is it possible to use the Android Bluetooth API on a regular Linux distribution (eg Ubuntu, or Raspbian) ?

My reasons for wanting to do this are:

1. Java is a language I'm very comfortable with
2. The Android API looks very comprehensive with support for Bluetooth LE.
3. I may wish to use this code in Android at some point in the future.

Comment: btw: I have googled this ... and I've found nothing... nor anyone else asking the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the Android Bluetooth API on a regular Linux distribution (eg Ubuntu, or Raspbian) ?

If by "the Android Bluetooth API" you mean the Java classes in the Android SDK, then no, you cannot just grab them and use them on Linux, OS X, Windows, or any other OS. Those Bluetooth API classes, [like `BluetoothAdapter`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.java), depend not only on classes that are part of the Android framework (not part of the SDK), but *those* classes in turn depend on core OS processes via IPC. Those processes, and the protocol that they speak, are part of Android itself.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. Pity .. my target hardware platform is the Raspberry Pi (for which there is no viable Android port... and seems unlikely there ever will)... and the Android BT API seems very nicely designed.